# Laravel 5: Create a multipage registration

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-middleware, laravel-authorization

How would I go about creating a multipage registration process in Laravel 5? I know I need to use Middleware, but I don't know how to use it for multiple views.

Comment: can you elaborate about "multipage registration" ?

Comment: @manshu : Basically once they complete filling out information on the first page they will be taken to a second page that contains additional information that they will have to fill out.

Comment: Save the first page information in a variable

Answer (score 1):

Add an extra column to your user's table, name it `step` to keep track of their registration process. Then after every successful form submit increment the step value.

You'd want to signup/register the user in the first step just so if they decide to come back you can redirect them to the correct step/view. This is also useful to remind the users by email to complete their registration.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use Ajax or any javascript related stuffs to go to the next page without reloading, store the inputs to the session and just get all the data from there.

Else if you're using Ajax/javscript/jquery, just make one big form and send all the data from the inputs.